# Video will not play on Edge

Tags: html, flash, video

I am using HTML5 to embed a video on my site. It works in all browsers except Edge.

Here is my code:

```
<video id="sampleMovie" width="509" height="280" preload autoplay>
<source src="breaking_news.mov" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
<source src="breaking_news.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
<source src="breaking_news.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"breaking_news.flv","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}}' />
</object>
</video>
```

I removed the full URL for the purpose of posting here.

Any idea on why it will not play in Edge?

Comment: Instead of making an `.mov` (for video tag) and also an `.flv` (for Flash app) just simply make an `mp4` file since both Flash and browsers are each capable of playing same MP4 files. No need for FLV in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Edge browser video developer guide for mp4, this is what is supported:

> Media File : Video MP4.
>   Extension setting : `.mp4`.
>   Mime type setting : `video/mp4`.

Based on the code you provided, the MP4 file you are providing has an extension type/container type of `.mov` which is not supported.

Thus, I recommend re-encoding your source video file so that it has the `.mp4` extension type, more than likely this is the issue. I would also look at the specific codec type you are specifying.

Lastly, I recommend looking at their full dev guide found here: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/html5/video

Hope this helps.